# Maven build works on Linux but fails on Windows

Tags: windows, maven, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin

I have a maven project which builds successfully on Linux, but fails on Windows. Its the same Java version(1.7), Maven version(3.5.2). Only difference is the OS. This is the error which I get in Windows:

```
[ERROR] Error building bundle wfapp-scan:scantasklistapp:bundle:1.8.1 : Service-Component: In component listener/addListener, Multiple references with the same name: com.ge.med.ct.wfplat.study.studyifc.tasklist.ScanTaskListListener*. Previous def: java.lang.Object*, this def:
[ERROR] Error(s) found in bundle configuration
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.242 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-12T17:47:17-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/444M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.4:bundle (default-bundle) on project scantasklistapp: Error(s) found in bundle configuration -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.4:bundle (default-bundle) on project scantasklistapp: Error(s) found in bundle configuration
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error(s) found in bundle configuration
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute (BundlePlugin.java:341)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute (BundlePlugin.java:224)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute (BundlePlugin.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Error(s) found in bundle configuration
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute (BundlePlugin.java:293)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute (BundlePlugin.java:224)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute (BundlePlugin.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I dont get this error when I build the same project on Linux.

My main pom already has the maven-bundle-plugin with the required version configured:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
</plugin>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What do you have inside your Service ? Maybe multiple references with the same name. Maybe Windows and Linux VM are handling this configuration task differently or maybe you have used something in your configuration which does not work on Windows only.

If I were you I will look deeply inside your file to look what it could cause that error, around lines with `com.ge.med.ct.wfplat.study.studyifc.tasklist.ScanTaskListListener`.

Maybe a config path written which is not compatible with Windows ?

```
[ERROR] Error building bundle wfapp-scan:scantasklistapp:bundle:1.8.1 : Service-Component: In component listener/addListener, Multiple references with the same name: com.ge.med.ct.wfplat.study.studyifc.tasklist.ScanTaskListListener*. Previous def: java.lang.Object*, this def:
```

Comment: No there aren't multiple references with the same name. If that was the case, the build would have failed on linux as well right? I did look into the area where `ScanTaskListListener` is used but I dont see any issues there. I think it is not some issue in the code(because the same code builds well on linux) but something to do with the OS environment itself and some config setting for windows..

Comment: Ok, then maybe there is a static call which is not allowed somewhere ? I think about that solution because of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47925047/390462.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I did go through this answer before, and no, there aren't any static methods. Again, if that was the case, the build would have failed in linux too right..

Comment: Maybe a Windows not compatible typo or an EOL char which is breaking the build on Windows only. Hard to guess without any code too. Post your whole configuration, as the error seems to be here.